# How to determine primary editor for a page/post

Tags: plugin-development

We are working on a plugin that is trying to hook into the WordPress Classic Editor, but only want to load the code if the Classic Editor itself is going to be used on the page/post for editing.

We don't want to load the code on the page/post editor page if it's one that a page builder like Elementor is set up on and the Classic Editor wont appear anyway. While we know how to check to see if a plugin is installed and active or not, since page builders can be active on the website but not being used on a specific page/post we we're looking for a way to check for that so the code will only run if the Classic Editor is actually going to show up.

Comment: it's possible that doing this will require adding checks for every page builder out there, there's no generic option you can read for this

Comment: What does your code actually need to do. Many hooks would only be relevant to the classic editor, so if you’re hooked into those then it would only be run for the classic editor.

Comment: The main thing we're having an issue with is a metabox we're adding that we only want to show up if the classic editor itself is going to show up. We're tying into the hook "add_meta_boxes" right now to do this, but it runs regardless of other page builders being used or not. If there is another hook to use, that would be great.